# Highcharts: legendItemClick: make background transparent instead of deleting it

Tags: charts, highcharts, legend, pie-chart, slice

I know how I can prevent from deleting a slice from pie chart,

```
legendItemClick: function () {
    return false;
}
```

but how can I make slice to be transparent instead of deleting it from chart?

I just want to be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ignoreHiddenPoints: false` see: http://jsfiddle.net/NZ9d7/